# Java class file not on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, classpath

I've tried opening class file in eclipse that I have copied pasted from the jar that I have imported into the project and am receiving this as first error:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The class file is not on the classpath.

Evidently I have included the class file incorrectly into my project. I need to use this class file to access Java applet. Suggestions please

Comment: refresh your project in eclipse ))

Comment: You said  in a comment, this is a PHP project. Why? How does the PHP interact with the Java applet? Could you post Java code from the applet that's giving you the error?

Answer (score 8):

Rather than trying to copy the class file into your project, you should reference the Jar that the class you want is part of.

Go to: project->properties->java build path->libraries tab->add external jars...

Comment: I'm using these files from within a PHP project

Comment: You should to make that clear in your question then! I've no experience developing PHP project in Eclipse, so can't help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on project > Maven > Update Project

worked for me :)